# How to change a vehicle route before it enters the map

Tags: python, sumo

I'm currently running some experiments on the [Bologna Acosta map](https://github.com/DLR-TS/sumo-scenarios/tree/main/bologna/acosta), computing alternative routes in Python and changing the route of the entered vehicles based on some heuristics and monitoring the change in the SUMO metrics.

In order to understand which vehicles have just entered the map I did this:

```
vehiclesInside = set()
while step < constants.HORIZON:
    traci.simulationStep(step)

    vehicles = set(traci.vehicle.getIDList())

    newVehicles = vehicles.difference(vehiclesInside)

    for vehicleId in newVehicles:
        route = traci.vehicle.getRoute(vehicleId)
        origin = route[0]
        destination = route[-1]
        newRoute = computeNewRoute(origin, destination)
        traci.vehicle.setRoute(vehicleId, newRoute)

    vehiclesInside = vehicles
    step += constants.TRACI_STEP
```

The problem is that, in this way, the vehicles pop up in entry points already in the lane best suited for them to achieve their original route and, when I subsequently change the route, the cars are all on the "wrong" lane causing an increasing of the DepartDelay metric (average time vehicle departures were delayed due to lack of road space).

Is there a way in Traci to update the vehicle routes before they are spawned in the map ?

Comment: For us to help you, provide a minimal reproducible problem set containing sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. What you have provided falls short of this goal. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Comment: Sorry. I have updated the original question. My question was not much about WHY the DepartDelay is increasing (I have already found the problem and how to solve it) but instead on how to use Traci to update the routes before the vehicles actually enter the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the list of vehicles which are loaded but may not have departed yet via `traci.simulation.getLoadedIDs` https://sumo.dlr.de/pydoc/traci._simulation.html#SimulationDomain-getLoadedIDList. You can set a new route for those vehicles just as for the departed ones.